# ForwardingCookieHandler.java line 136

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, crash

I am getting errors from Crashlytics, and I actually don't know how to resolve it ,can someone help me please.I am getting this error in firebase, actually from samsung mobile, I couldn't find how to reproduce it, or any information about it. I will be very grateful for any advice. Thank you in advance

Sorry for my English )

```
Fatal Exception: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.webview
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getFactoryClass(WebViewFactory.java:174)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:109)
       at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:42)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.getCookieManager(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:136)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.get(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:53)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.websocket.WebSocketModule.getCookie(WebSocketModule.java:392)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.websocket.WebSocketModule.connect(WebSocketModule.java:100)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

---

```
Caused by android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.webview
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:164)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getFactoryClass(WebViewFactory.java:146)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:109)
       at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:42)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.getCookieManager(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:136)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.get(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:53)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.websocket.WebSocketModule.getCookie(WebSocketModule.java:392)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.websocket.WebSocketModule.connect(WebSocketModule.java:100)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```